# Using 'xargs' in GIT for Windows bash

Tags: git, bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to automate my work with some nice command line scripts. I have one script (`jenkins_cli.sh`) that communicates with a Jenkins Server and which looks like this:

```
cd $1

if [ -z ${JENKINS_CREDENTIALS+x} -o -z ${JENKINS_SERVER+x} ]
  then
    JENKINS_SERVER=$(<jenkins_url.txt)
    JENKINS_CREDENTIALS=$(<credentials.txt)
fi

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_SERVER -auth $JENKINS_CREDENTIALS ${@:2}
```

This works fine.

For example if I call `./jenkins_cli.sh localhost/ list-jobs` I get a list of Jobs currently running on my local Jenkins Server. However, if I try to do something more fancy (e.g.: `./jenkins_cli.sh localhost/ list-jobs | xargs -L1 ./jenkins-cli localhost/ delete-job` I get the following error: `'RROR: No such job 'test_job`. The job `test_job` **does** exist. The job `'test_job` **does not** exist. How does this character `'` end up in my command?

I am guessing this has something to do with the fact that I am using the bash that shipped with GIT for Windows or how it deals with newlines or how I am handling parameters in my script/etc.. If I execute `./jenkins_cli.sh localhost/ list-jobs | xargs -L1 echo` I get the expected result without any quotes.. I really don't know how to debug this any further. I have a solution for this problem where I just write the job-list to a file and then read each line and pass it to my custom script, but I really want to implement it with `xargs` :)

Comment: I forgot to mention: if I use `./jenkins_cli localhost/ delete-job test_job` it does delete the job as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the output from your `jenkins` commands uses the DOS end-of-line style (`\r\n`) of output, but the git shell commands expect the classic UNIX end-of-line style (`\n`).

The thing is that `xargs` sees the stray `\r` as special characters at the end of the lines and try to escape them. But then, even if all goes well, the argument to the next command will not be `test_job` but `test_job\r` (the `\r` may be invisible).

The easy solution is to use `dos2unix`:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_SERVER -auth $JENKINS_CREDENTIALS ${@:2} | dos2unix
```

Comment: The `\r` isn't entirely invisible: it causes the "cursor" to jump back to the beginning of the line. This is why you see `'RROR` rather than `ERROR`: the closing `'` is preceded by `\r` and so it ends up at the beginning of the line.